# Insert foreign keys in mysql with Python

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys

I need to get data from an API and insert it into mysql with Python. The request and the insertion is fine and works well but I try to insert foreign keys from db and insert it to tickets_facts table. The only problem is that it inserts 1 for every foreign key in every row. If i look in my db, I notice that there are a lot of other ID's and not just 1. I tried a few times and i tried another code to insert it but that gives me the same output. I work with Pycharm and i tried another editor but i get the same output

Can anyone help me with the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import pymysql

# Definieer alle db en api paramenters
host = ""
username = ""
password = ""
database = ""
api_url = "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/cinemavisits?key=ed7c6150"

# data ophalen van apiresponse = requests.get(api_url)
processed_response = response.json()

# Connectie maken met db
db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, password=password, database=database)
cursor = db.cursor()

# elke record die we krijgen uit API loopen
for purchase in processed_response:

# Ticket facts# vergelijk de data in de db met die van API om de foreign key te achterhalen
original_ticket_price = str(purchase["original_ticket_price"])
purchasing_ticket_price = str(purchase["purchasing_price_tickets"])
discount_ticket = str(purchase["discount_on_tickets"])
purchase_ticket_date = str(purchase["purchase_date"])
group_size = str(purchase["group_size"])
original_food_price = str(purchase["original_food_price"])
purchasing_food_price = str(purchase["purchasing_price_food"])
discount_food = str(purchase["discount_on_food"])
purchase_food_date = str(purchase["purchase_date"])
purchase_food_amount = str(purchase["group_size"])
app_version = str(purchase["app_version"])

movie = 
cursor.execute("""select movieID from movies_dimensionwhere movie_name = '"""+movie_name+"""'AND distributor = '"""+distributor+"""'""")

cinema = 
cursor.execute("""select cinemaID from cinema_dimensionwhere cinema_name = '"""+cinema_name+"""'AND cinema_location = '"""+cinema_location+"""'""")

booker = 
cursor.execute("""select bookerID from customer_dimensionwhere booker_first_name = '"""+booker_first_name+"""'AND booker_last_name = '"""+booker_last_name+"""'AND booker_age = '"""+booker_age+"""'AND booker_email = '"""+booker_email+"""'AND booker_gender = '"""+booker_gender+"""'AND booker_address = '"""+booker_address+"""'AND booker_city = '"""+booker_city+"""'""")

popcorn = 
cursor.execute("""select popcornID from popcorn_dimensionwhere popcorn_size = '"""+popcorn_size+"""'AND popcorn_taste = '"""+popcorn_taste+"""'""")

# Controlleer of record al in tabel voorkomt, om dubbele data te voorkomen
cursor.execute("""select * from tickets_facts 
where movieID = '"""+str(movie)+"""'
AND cinemaID = '"""+str(cinema)+"""'
AND bookerID = '"""+str(booker)+"""'
AND original_ticket_price = '"""+original_ticket_price+"""'
AND purchasing_ticket_price = '"""+purchasing_ticket_price+"""'
AND discount_ticket = '"""+discount_ticket+"""'
AND purchase_ticket_date = '"""+purchase_ticket_date+"""'
AND group_size = '"""+group_size+"""'
AND popcornID = '"""+str(popcorn)+"""'
AND original_food_price = '"""+original_food_price+"""'
AND purchasing_food_price = '"""+purchasing_food_price+"""'
AND discount_food = '"""+discount_food+"""'
AND purchase_food_date = '"""+purchase_food_date+"""'
AND purchase_food_amount = '"""+purchase_food_amount+"""'
AND app_version = '"""+app_version+"""'""")

# Aantal rijen tellen die worden opgehaald uit db
resultcount = cursor.rowcount

# Zodra de record niet bestaat wordt die ingevoerd in dbif resultcount == 0:sql = """Insert into tickets_facts
(movieID, cinemaID, bookerID, original_ticket_price, purchasing_ticket_price, discount_ticket, purchase_ticket_date, group_size,popcornID, original_food_price, purchasing_food_price, discount_food, purchase_food_date, purchase_food_amount, app_version)
VALUES ('"""+str(movie)+"""', '"""+str(cinema)+"""', '"""+str(booker)+"""','"""+original_ticket_price+"""', '"""+purchasing_ticket_price+"""', '"""+discount_ticket+"""','"""+purchase_ticket_date+"""', '"""+group_size+"""', '"""+str(popcorn)+"""', '"""+original_food_price+"""', '"""+purchasing_food_price+"""','"""+discount_food+"""', '"""+purchase_food_date+"""', '"""+purchase_food_amount+"""', '"""+app_version+"""')"""

try:
# Voer sql command uit en commit in db
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

except Exception as e:
# Als iets fout gaat, niets veranderen
print(e)
db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your many indentation errors, the expression `'"""+str(movie)+"""'` evaluates to a string whose value is `"""+str(movie)+"""`. You probably mean something closer to `"'"+str(movie)+"'"`. But that only works if `movie` has no single-quote character in it. And you are not correctly fetching results from your SELECT statements. How could your posted code have run at all?

You should be using *prepared statements*. Your code should look something like the following (I can only guess at the proper indentation):

```py
import requests
import json
import pymysql

# Definieer alle db en api paramenters
host = ""
username = ""
password = ""
database = ""
api_url = "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/cinemavisits?key=ed7c6150"

# data ophalen van apiresponse = requests.get(api_url)
processed_response = response.json()

# Connectie maken met db
db = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=username, password=password, database=database)
cursor = db.cursor()

# elke record die we krijgen uit API loopen
for purchase in processed_response:

    # Ticket facts# vergelijk de data in de db met die van API om de foreign key te achterhalen
    original_ticket_price = str(purchase["original_ticket_price"])
    purchasing_ticket_price = str(purchase["purchasing_price_tickets"])
    discount_ticket = str(purchase["discount_on_tickets"])
    purchase_ticket_date = str(purchase["purchase_date"])
    group_size = str(purchase["group_size"])
    original_food_price = str(purchase["original_food_price"])
    purchasing_food_price = str(purchase["purchasing_price_food"])
    discount_food = str(purchase["discount_on_food"])
    purchase_food_date = str(purchase["purchase_date"])
    purchase_food_amount = str(purchase["group_size"])
    app_version = str(purchase["app_version"])
    
    cursor.execute("""select movieID from movies_dimensionwhere movie_name = %s AND distributor = %s""", (movie_name, distributor))
    movie = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    cursor.execute("""select cinemaID from cinema_dimensionwhere cinema_name = %s AND cinema_location = %s""", (cinema_name, cinema_location))
    cinema = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    cursor.execute("""select bookerID from customer_dimension where booker_first_name = %s
    AND booker_last_name = %s AND booker_age = %s AND booker_email = %s
    AND booker_gender = %s AND booker_address = %s AND booker_city = %s""",
    (booker_first_name, booker_last_name, booker_age, booker_email, booker_gender, booker_address, booker_city))
    booker = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    cursor.execute("""select popcornID from popcorn_dimensionwhere popcorn_size = %s AND popcorn_taste = %s""", (popcorn_size, popcorn_taste))
    popcorn = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    # Controlleer of record al in tabel voorkomt, om dubbele data te voorkomen
    cursor.execute("""select * from tickets_facts 
    where movieID = %s
    AND cinemaID = %s
    AND bookerID = %s
    AND original_ticket_price = %s
    AND purchasing_ticket_price = %s
    AND discount_ticket = %s
    AND purchase_ticket_date = %s
    AND group_size = %s
    AND popcornID = %s
    AND original_food_price = %s
    AND purchasing_food_price = %s
    AND discount_food = %s
    AND purchase_food_date = %s
    AND purchase_food_amount = %s
    AND app_version = %s""",
    (str(movie), str(cinema), str(booker), original_ticket_price, purchasing_ticket_price, discount_ticket, purchase_ticket_date, group_size,
     str(popcorn), original_food_price, purchasing_food_price, discount_food, purchase_food_date, purchase_food_amount, app_version)
    )
    
    # Aantal rijen tellen die worden opgehaald uit db
    resultcount = cursor.rowcount
    
    # Zodra de record niet bestaat wordt die ingevoerd in db
    if resultcount == 0:
        sql = """Insert into tickets_facts(movieID, cinemaID, bookerID, original_ticket_price, purchasing_ticket_price, discount_ticket,
purchase_ticket_date, group_size, popcornID, original_food_price, purchasing_food_price, discount_food, purchase_food_date, purchase_food_amount, app_version)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""       
        try:
            # Voer sql command uit en commit in db
            cursor.execute(sql, (str(movie), str(cinema), str(booker), original_ticket_price, purchasing_ticket_price, discount_ticket,
                                 purchase_ticket_date, group_size, str(popcorn), original_food_price, purchasing_food_price,
                                 discount_food, purchase_food_date, purchase_food_amount, app_version))
            db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            # Als iets fout gaat, niets veranderen
            print(e)
            db.rollback()
    
db.close()
```

Comment: Nice works fine, but in my DB the "original_price_ticket" is a decimal, and now python puts str in my db so i only got for example 89 dollar and not 89.50 dollar

Comment: I think you mean `original_ticket_price`. What is the value of and type of `purchase["purchasing_price_tickets"]` that is being converted to a string and the exact type and **precision** of db column `original_ticket_price`? If the column is DECIMAL with at least 2 digits of precision following the decimal point, for example DECIMAL(6, 2), then you should have no problem whether variable `original_ticket_price` is of type `Decimal` or a string provided the string is something like '89.50'. But if the data is '89' or the column definition is like DECIMAL(6), then the db will only have 89.